# Restructure (swap layers of) the list of lists

Tags: r

Here is an example list of lists of my real data:

```r
df <- c(1, 2, 3)
x <- list(df, df, df)
y <- list(df, df, df)
z <- list(df, df, df)
lista <- list(x, y, z)
listb <- list(x, y, z)
lols <- list(a = lista, b =listb)
```

`lols` has a structure like this:

```
        lols
         |
      ________
     |        |
     a        b
     |        |
   _____    _____
  |  |  |  |  |  |
  x  y  z  x  y  z
```

I want to restructure `lols` into the following shape:

```
          lols
           |
      ___________
     |     |     |  
     x     y     z  
     |     |     |
    ___   ___   ___
   |   | |   | |   |
   a   b a   b a   b
```

I managed to do it using `for` loops, but I am not sure if it is correct, and if it works efficiently with very large real data:

```r
newl <- rep(list(list()), length(lols[[1]]))

for (i in seq_along(lols)) {
  for(j in seq_along(lols[[i]])) {
    newl[[j]][[i]] <- lols[[i]][[j]]
  }
}
```

Is there a faster way to do it, as `for` loop is believed very slow in R?

In my code the list names are dropped, how can I keep the names?

EDIT:
A microbenchmark based on mine and the accepted answer and `purrr::transpose()` as suggested by the comment

```r
fun1 <- function(ls) {
  newl <- rep(list(list()), length(ls[[1]]))
  for (i in seq_along(ls)) {
    for (j in seq_along(ls[[i]])) {
      newl[[j]][[i]] <- ls[[i]][[j]]
    }
  }
  
  return(newl)
}

fun2 <- function(ls) {
  nm <- el(lapply(ls, names))
  newl <- lapply(nm, \(i) lapply(ls, '[[', i)) |> setNames(nm)
}

fun3 <- function(ls) {
  purrr::transpose(ls)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fun1(loaded), fun2(loaded), fun3(loaded), times = 1000)

#> Unit: microseconds
#>          expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq     max neval
#>  fun1(loaded) 7631.3 8029.35 8877.8146 8296.65 8946.65 37443.3  1000
#>  fun2(loaded)   66.6   81.60  118.0540  113.75  135.00   923.9  1000
#>  fun3(loaded)    2.9    3.90   16.0451   15.60   27.80    70.7  1000
```

Comment: You can use `purrr::transpose()`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I've amended my benchmark, seems that `purrr::transpose()` is really fast and does exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better name your list elements, then you may loop over the lists' first layer `names`.

```
nm <- el(lapply(lols, names))
newl <- lapply(nm, \(i) lapply(lols, '[[', i)) |> setNames(nm)
```

### Gives

```
str(newl)
# List of 3
# $ x:List of 2
# ..$ a:List of 3
# .. ..$ k: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ l: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ m: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# ..$ b:List of 3
# .. ..$ k: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ l: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ m: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# $ y:List of 2
# ..$ a:List of 3
# .. ..$ k: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ l: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ m: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# ..$ b:List of 3
# .. ..$ k: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ l: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ m: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# $ z:List of 2
# ..$ a:List of 3
# .. ..$ k: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ l: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ m: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# ..$ b:List of 3
# .. ..$ k: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ l: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# .. ..$ m: num [1:3] 1 2 3
```

Or also without renaming, try

```
lapply(1:3, \(i) lapply(lols, '[[', i)) |> setNames(c('x', 'y', 'z'))
```

---

*Data:*

```
lols <- list(a = list(x = list(k = c(1, 2, 3), l = c(1, 2, 3), m = c(1, 
2, 3)), y = list(k = c(1, 2, 3), l = c(1, 2, 3), m = c(1, 2, 
3)), z = list(k = c(1, 2, 3), l = c(1, 2, 3), m = c(1, 2, 3))), 
    b = list(x = list(k = c(1, 2, 3), l = c(1, 2, 3), m = c(1, 
    2, 3)), y = list(k = c(1, 2, 3), l = c(1, 2, 3), m = c(1, 
    2, 3)), z = list(k = c(1, 2, 3), l = c(1, 2, 3), m = c(1, 
    2, 3))))
```

Comment: Looks like in your solution there is an excess layer: List of 3
 $ x:List of 2
  ..$ a:List of 1
  .. ..$ x:List of 3, how to get rid of the (a: List of 1, x: List of 3), to make it become (a: List of 3)?

Comment: @TianjianQin I see, `lapply(nm, \(i) lapply(lols, '[[', i)) |> setNames(nm)` perhaps?

Comment: And please see the comment below the question. `purrr::transpose()` is way faster. Although we don't need to reinvent a wheel, the techniques in your solution will be helpful to other similar questions

Comment: @TianjianQin Also consider that some are not able or willing to install additional packages.